# Should I return the result of deferred.resolve/reject?

Tags: javascript, promise, q, deferred

When working with Q deferreds, should I return the result of `deferred.resolve` and `deferred.reject`?

```
function foo() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  service.doSomethingAsync({
    success: function() {
      deferred.resolve(); // should I return the result of resolve here?
    }, 
    fail: function(err) {
      deferred.reject(err); // should I return the result of reject here?
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: .promise is not a function. Do return deferred.promise;

Comment: @BasSlagter thanks, typo.

Comment: They don't return any value. Neither does your service care about the result value of the `success`/`fail` callbacks. So what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to return after early resolve/reject?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32536049/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be changed to:

```
function foo() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  service.doSomethingAsync({
    success: deferred.resolve, 
    fail:  deferred.reject
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

What you want to return from the foo() method depends on what you want to achieve of course. In many cases you hide the internals and just return an empty array or null if something fails. But..if it is needed...you can throw an error. If you want to handle things outside the function, yes, return the error object for example...like I said...it depends.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess that means that the answer to my original question is "no"?

Comment: @BenAston in most cases I'd say that yes...see my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, your comment is ambiguous. You would say that the answer is "no"?

Comment: Yes, I say the answer to your initial question is no. Sorry for the confusing comment ;)