# Trouble forming a promise chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, bluebird

I have a function that has to connect to DB to get a upload token, then upload a file, then close the stream and log the file in DB. I'm having trouble chaining all this together.

```
var saveNewRequest = function (image_arr) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://' + AppVar.ServerUrlWithPort + '/restapi/MtReqNewRequest_SaveData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'SessionId': AppVar.SessionId,
            'Name': $('#MtReqNewRequest_name').val(),
            'Desc': $('#MtReqNewRequest_desc').val(),
            'Obj': $('#MtReqNewRequest_obj').val(),
            'Priority': $('#MtReqNewRequest_priority2').val(),
            'Status': $('#MtReqNewRequest_status2').val(),
            'Type': $('#MtReqNewRequest_type2').val()
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        timeout: 10000
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response.ResultCode === '0') {
            if (image_arr.length != 0) {
                //this is recursively called upload function which returns jQuery promise (this works as intended)
                // the promise resolves with RequestId which I need later on
                return uploadImages(image_arr, image_arr.length, 0, response.RequestId)
            } else {
               //I would like this to return just this RequestId
                Promise.resolve(response.RequestId)
            }
        } else {
            Promise.reject().promise();
        }
    }).fail(function (x, t, m) {
        if (t === "timeout") {
            reject("Timeout: " + t);
        } else {
            reject($.i18n('Error-RetrivingDataProblem'));
        }
    })
}
```

And I call this in an event:

```
    MtReq.saveNewRequest(image_arr).then(function (output) {
        AppVar.nav.popPage().then(function () {
            Utility.hideModalWithProgressBar();
            if (!isNaN(output)) {
                setTimeout(500, AppVar.nav.pushPage("MtReqRequestPage.html", { animation: "slide", id: output }));
            }
        })
    }).catch(function (e) {
        Utility.hideModalWithProgressBar();
        ons.notification.alert(e);
    })
```

I need to pass the RequestID to the `AppVar.nav.pushPage`, to open the page I just created. However, I'm getting whole response of the very first Ajax request in `saveNewRequest`.

This is Cordova app, using OnsenUI framework (but that's not relevant to the problem). Also, I'm using latest BluebirdJs as Promise polyfill (which to my knowledge should make JS and jQuery promises compatible).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note, `Promise.reject()` does not have a `.promise()` method. `reject()` is not defined within `.fail()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning how promises work. It's pretty confusing at times. Nevertheless, that doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `.then()` for `.done()`; `.done()` returns same jQuery promise object returned by `$.ajax()`. `return` the `Promise` or other value from `.then()`.

```
var saveNewRequest = function (image_arr) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://' + AppVar.ServerUrlWithPort + '/restapi/MtReqNewRequest_SaveData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'SessionId': AppVar.SessionId,
            'Name': $('#MtReqNewRequest_name').val(),
            'Desc': $('#MtReqNewRequest_desc').val(),
            'Obj': $('#MtReqNewRequest_obj').val(),
            'Priority': $('#MtReqNewRequest_priority2').val(),
            'Status': $('#MtReqNewRequest_status2').val(),
            'Type': $('#MtReqNewRequest_type2').val()
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        timeout: 10000
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ResultCode === '0') {
            if (image_arr.length != 0) {
                //this is recursively called upload function which returns jQuery promise (this works as intended)
                // the promise resolves with RequestId which I need later on
                return uploadImages(image_arr, image_arr.length, 0, response.RequestId)
            } else {
                //I would like this to return just this RequestId
                // added `return`
                return Promise.resolve(response.RequestId)
            }
        } else {
            // note `return`, removed `.promise()`
            return Promise.reject()        
        }
    }).fail(function (x, t, m) {
        if (t === "timeout") {
            // included `Promise`, chain `.reject()`
            // note, `return`
            return Promise.reject("Timeout: " + t);
        } else {
            // note `Promise.reject()`, added `return`
            return Promise.reject($.i18n('Error-RetrivingDataProblem'));
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Btw, I was under impression I don't `return` resolve/reject (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536049/do-i-need-to-return-after-early-resolve-reject). Or does it just not matter?

Comment: `resolve()`, `reject()` within `Promise` constructor is not same as `Promise.resolve()`, `Promise.reject()`

Comment: I see. Thanks. I will look into it.