# Firebase promises-based Auth flow always redirects

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, es6-promise

I'd like to have the copy-paste "Firebase Authorize using Google" flow for my app -- and I do, with one problem: it always redirects to Google, even when it is already authorized and bounces right back.  Is there any way to have it *not* bounce through Google when the user has recently authenticated and is a returning user?

```js
Promise.resolve().then(function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.group('init');

    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "MY KEY",
      authDomain: "MINE.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://MINE.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "MINE.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "ALSOMINE"
    });

    // Using this to make sure not in intermediate state
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      console.log('User state stablilized.');
      resolve();
    });
  });
}).then(function() {
  // All the various login states
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      console.log('You were already logged in - great!')
      resolve(firebase.auth().currentUser);
    }

    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
      if (result.user) {
        console.log('Welcome back and congratulations on your successful login!', result.user);
        resolve(result.user);
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged in, not returning - time to send you on your way.');
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
        console.log('You should never see this line because it redirected!');
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Returning from redirect login error:', error);
      reject(error);
    });
  });

}).then(function(user) {
  console.log('Signed in user', firebase.auth().currentUser.email);
  // LETS ROCK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call:

resolve(firebase.auth().currentUser);

Call:

return;

Comment: Freakin brilliant, and inpired my new answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536049/do-i-need-to-return-after-early-resolve-reject/41095255#41095255