# Trouble Understanding Async/Await

Tags: node.js, async-await, reverse-dns

Simple example I think. I want to use Express to return a users IP and hostname upon request. But resolving that hostname from the IP is giving me a little bit of trouble.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    logRequest(req, res);
});

async function logRequest(req, res) {
    res.send({
        ip: req.ip,
        hostname: await getRemoteHostName(req.ip)
    });
}

async function getRemoteHostName(ip) {
    await require('dns').reverse(ip, (err, domains) => {
        if (err) { handleError(err); return; }
        return domains.map(s => s.toLowerCase());
    });
}
```

All I'm getting back is my IP `{ip: 192.168.10.100}` when I expect that I should be getting back my hostname too. If I `console.log` my hostname it prints to console but the hostname is not sent back by express in the response. What am I doing wrong? I feel like express is sending the response back before `dns.reverse` can finish the lookup but I want that lookup to finish *and then* return the response.

Comment: It's not necessary to understand async/await to make this work. You need to understand promises. `dns.reverse` doesn't return a promise so it cannot be awaited. Promisify it.

Comment: remove `await` before my `require('dns')...` and wrap it in a `new Promise()` is what you're saying?

Comment: That's correct. For last Node versions there's already promisified version of it, as the answer mentions.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `callback` and `async/await`

`await` should be combined with a `Promise`

In your case `dns.reverse` is not a promise and return nothing.

First, you need to use [dns promise](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_promises_api)

Then you need to update `getRemoteHostName` to return hostnames and handle errors

```
const { Resolver } = require('dns').promises;
const resolver = new Resolver();

async function getRemoteHostName(ip) {
  try {
    const hostnames = await resolver.reverse(ip)
    // your logic here
    return hostnames
  } catch(error) {
    // handle error here
  }
}
```

Comment: So in newer versions of node you don't need `... = require('dns').promises;`, just `const { Resolver } = require('dns');`

Comment: The linked docs ... are `11.0` ... what's newer than that? The docs show to use `.promises`

Comment: Crap, sorry. I'm on v8.11. So I need to wrap my call in a promsie. Correct

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what exactly you need to do for 8.x. Looks like you might be able to use util.promsify for some stuff but probably safer to just convert it yourself using a `function(err,data){return new Promise(...)}` type of thing

Comment: @CodyG. could you double check my answer I posted below please and see if that makes sense to you? And if I'm missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

With node v8.11.3 I needed to promisify my `getRemoteHostName()` method.

```
function getRemoteHostName(ip) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    require('dns').reverse(ip, (err, domains) => {
      if (err) { reject(err); }
      resolve(domains.map(d => d.toLowerCase()));
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(`error: ${error}`);
  });
}
```

After that I wrapped my `logRequest()` with an `async/await` like so

```
async function logRequest(req, res) {
  const client = {
    ip: req.ip,
    hostname: await getRemoteHostName(req.ip)
  };

  res.send(client);
}
```

At which point I could make a request to Express with

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    logRequest(req, res);
});
```

And get my hostname as expected.

Comment: get rid of the `.catch()` you're swallowing the errors, and I personally do `if(err){reject(err)}else{resolve(...)}` I think you can run into asynchronous issues if reject is then passed to an asynchronous error handling function ... resolve would be called too, which would seem like it would throw some other type of weird error that promises can only be resolved or rejected once but I actually don't know what would happen.

Comment: good question resource on it though, which I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536049/do-i-need-to-return-after-early-resolve-reject  ... basically I don't like the lack of using `else` or a `return` because you can indeed run code unintended.