# Vue.js component does not emit to parent after successful axios call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using

```
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vuex": "^3.1.1"
```

My `vuex` action looks like this and calls a remote interface using `axios`. The request does work and it receives a valid response.

```
skipQuestion({commit}, payload) {
    let params = {
        answer: {
            id: payload.id,
            skipped: true,
        }
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit(UPDATE_LOADING, true);
        Remote.put(`/answer.json`, params)
            .then((response) => {
                commit(UPDATE_LOADING, false);
                commit(SKIP_QUESTION, payload.id);
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                commit(UPDATE_LOADING, false);
                reject(error);
            })
    })
},
```

The component `Question` does have the following method `skip`, which calls the `vuex` action `skipQuestion` and should emit the `skip` event to the parent component.

```
...mapActions(['skipQuestion']),
skip(evt) {
    let payload = { id: this.question_id };
    this.skipQuestion(payload).then( () => {
        this.$emit('skip', this.uuid);
    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

The problem is, that the `skip` event is not emitted to the parent when using it within the `then` block of the action. The vue developer console for chrome also confirms, that the `skip` event was fired. If I put the emit outside the block, everything works. Any suggestions whats going wrong?

## Edit 1

Also tried the following code and both log statements are printed to the console.

```
skip(evt) {
    let payload = { id: this.question_id };
    let vm = this; 
    this.skipQuestion(payload).then( () => {
        console.log('before skip emit');
        vm.$emit('skip', this.uuid);
        console.log('after skip emit');
    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

## Edit 2

Here is the template code which is used to listen to the child events:

```
<question v-bind="question"
          :key="question.uuid"
          v-if="questionReady"
          v-on:skip="onSkipQuestion"
          v-on:answer="onAnswerQuestion">
</question>
```

As told before, if not using the Promise/then-block returned by the `axios` request, the emit does work. Below you'll find the method which should be called:

```
methods: {
  onSkipQuestion(payload) {
    // this code is not executed
    console.log('onSkipQuestion')

    //....
  },


  //....
}
```

Comment: Maybe not the definitive solution to your problem, but you should definitely try switching to await / async instead of using raw promises

Comment: I'm assuming that you have on your parent component something like `v-on:skip=somfunc` to listen to the `skip` event. is that right?

Comment: Yes of course, I also tried `@skip=somefunc`. As mentioned if I emit it outside the `then` block everything works fine.

Comment: Can you add your template code ?

Comment: Maybe try to use ```.bind()``` for this method, then maybe your parent commponent will also see this event. Or maybe try to make ```skip``` arrow function inside ```data() {return { skip: () => ....}} ```

Answer (score 4):

Summarize your information given:

> The vue developer console for chrome also confirms, that the skip event was fired.

---

#### TL;DR

- [`vm.$emit`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/d7d8ff06b70cf1a2345e3839c503fdb08d75ba49/src/core/instance/events.js#L118) bassically calls every method listed in `vm._events[eventName]`
- `v-on` gets registered via `context.listeners` in [`createElemet`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/861aea16615a9736eab6af6d05fa5500ae4d6c37/src/core/vdom/create-component.js#L193) and injected via [`updateListeners`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/861aea16615a9736eab6af6d05fa5500ae4d6c37/src/core/vdom/helpers/update-listeners.js#L53)

---

### Basically you can debug using `debugger` statement:

```
skip(evt) {
    let payload = { id: this.question_id };
    this.skipQuestion(payload).then( () => {
        debugger; // scope -> _events & scope -> $parent.componentInstance
        // or console.log(JSON.stringify(this._events))
        this.$emit('skip', this.uuid);
    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Then you know whats happening.

---

Things to check:

- valid `this` scope
- valid `parent`
- actually triggered as resolved
- `vm._events` registered

Answer (score 2):

You have lost the reference to `this` inside the then block. The reference is now the callback function called. Instead do this

```
 ...mapActions(['skipQuestion']),
    skip(evt) {
        let payload = { id: this.question_id };
        let vm = this; // Preserve Vue instance for use inside block
        this.skipQuestion(payload).then( () => {
            vm.$emit('skip', vm.uuid);
        }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before but it doesn't change anything. The event is not emitted to the parent.

Comment: strange.... Have you confirmed the `then` blocked is being called by adding in a console.log statement?

Comment: Yes, I added a `console.log` before and after the `emit` and both are printed within the `then` block. Did update the code example.

Comment: If you change `this` to **vm**, then inside the emit statement `this.uuid` should be changed too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that you don't return resolve() or reject() in skipQuestion().

Anyway, assuming your application uses **ES2017** (or higher), or if not then **Babel**, I would refine the function to use `async / await` structure so that `this` would not be at any risk (referring to [Varun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449949/5762431)), and not in any risk if `skipQuestion()` doesn't return anything, like as is currently:

```js
async skip(evt) {
    let payload = { id: this.question_id };
    try {
      let result = await skipQuestion(payload)
      this.$emit('skip', this.uuid);
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Not returning `resolve / reject` is a known source of bugs in case of `Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})` syntax

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently we are using `Babel`. We tried your update code and also removed the returning of the extra `Promise`, but still the emit is not promoted to the parent component.

Comment: What do you mean "removed the returning of the extra Promise"?  
Can you edit your question adding the changes you've done?

Comment: The store actions now returns `return Remote.put(`/answer.json`, params)
                    .then((response) => {
                        commit(UPDATE_LOADING, false);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        commit(UPDATE_LOADING, false);
                    })`

Comment: You don't need to remove the promise syntax.. Anyway, please return something in the `then` and `catch` blocks too! You use `then` and `catch` when initiating skipQuestion() and I assume it doesn't get hit because nothing is being returned

Comment: Can you give an example to your statement "Not returning resolve / reject is a known source of bugs" - this should be not the case o0? At least for the promise state - unless you run blocking code after resolving/rejecting within the promise... i am curious

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the case here indeed.  
For further explanation about how it can get messy, please read Ori's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536083/5762431)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and could not for the life of me figure out what was going on. All I can think of is that somehow the component is losing the ability to emit events while awaiting the promise resolution.

Anyway, my solution was to emit the promise itself, like this:

```
skip(evt) {
    let payload = { id: this.question_id };
    this.$emit('skip', skipQuestion(payload));
}
```

And on the parent, you can do

```
... @skip="receive_skip($event)" ...

...

methods: {
    receive_skip(skipped) {
        skipped
        .then((data) => {
            // do something on success
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // do something on fail
        });
    }
}
```

It's not as clean and elegant, but it gets the job done.