# what is being promised in the promise returned by .then ( ) method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My question id related to Javascript promises. The promise constructor allows us to write the logic to resolve or reject. For example

```
let x = true;
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
if (x == true){                              // Reject - Resolve logic 
    resolve('Success!');
  }
else {
    reject('Reject');
  }
});
```

But now if I chain it with a `.then ( () => console.log('Hello'))` , how does it get accepted or rejected without provided logic?

```
promise1.then(() => console.log('Hello') , undefined)
        .then(undefined , () => console.log('World'))
        .catch( () => console.log('Error'));
```

My question is:

**1. `new Promise` is either accepted or rejected and then the `.then()'s` onFullilled or onRejected is called. Also, `.then()` returns a new Promise. So, what is being promised in the returned promise by `.then()`?**

**2. Where do I provide the logic to either resolve or reject the promise returned by `.then()`?  (Like I did in the constructor above)**

Also, According to my knowledge - The functions resolve and reject are already present in JS and they mutate the Promise state

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to omit the `else` in your `if (x == true)`, meaning it will both resolve **and** reject when x is true?

Comment: @Wyck typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Wyck a resolved promise cannot be rejected. `console.assert(true === await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(true); reject(false)}))`

Comment: @BlueWater86 Good style not to reject after resolving:  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536049/do-i-need-to-return-after-early-resolve-reject  It **was** a typo.  See lynxx's comment.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to point out that a promise cannot be both resolved and rejected.

Comment: @BlueWater86 For sure.  I made the comment because it helps to avoid putting focus on the behaviour of calling `reject` after calling `resolve`, which is irrelevant for this question.  The intent of the question is more concise now.

Comment: Perhaps answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43155226/1563833)  The magic of `then` is that If you return something value-like, then it returns a promise that resolves with the value.  If you return something promise-like then it returns the promise.

Answer (score 1):

A picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

Comment: That picture (and the 1000 words it stands in for) is not related to the question at all, which asks about the `.then()` method

Answer (score 0):

```js
function promise1(data) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(++data);
 });
}

function promise2(data) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(++data);
 });
}

promise1(1)
 .then(data => promise2(data))
 .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly mentioned a promise always returns a new promise. That can be either in **pending** or **resolved** state.

Further if it resolves, it can either be ***rejected with a reason*** (meaning promise didn't did what it was supposed to do) or ***resolved with a value*** (meaning promise successfully completed its task).

```
let x = true;
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
if (x === true){                              
    resolve('Success!');
  }
else {
    reject('Reject');
  }
});
```

Now, if you use this promise somewhere like,

```
promise2 = promise1.then(val => {
  console.log(val); //logs "Success!"
  return "resolved value for promise2"
})
```

Further,

```
promise3 = promise2.then(val => {
  console.log(val); //logs "resolved value for promise2"
  return "some resolved value"
})
```

Now going back to the constructor function, for `x=false`,

```
promise2 = promise1.catch(err => {
  console.log(err) //logs "Reject";
  return "resolved value from catch block";
}) 

promise3 = promise2.then(val => {
  console.log(val); //logs "resolved value from catch block"
  return "some resolved value"
})
```

or you can throw an error so as to propagate it,

```
promise2 = promise1.catch(err => {
  console.log(err) //logs "Reject";
  throw "rejected value from catch";
}) 

promise3 = promise2.catch(val => {
  console.log(val); //logs "rejected value from catch"
  throw err;
})
```

Important part is **if you are throwing or returning from catch block**?
Read more on [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).