# How to stop processing continuing past a promise reject

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have async code that I'd like to stop running when I `reject`.

Note:

```
let ingestPromises = event.Records.map(async (record, i) => {
    let camera = JSON.parse(record.body)
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        let imageBuffer;
        try {
            imageBuffer = await retrieveImageFromURI(camera.ing_uri)
            console.log(`Record #${i} Successful Ingestion from URI`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Going to reject");
            reject({ 'Task': `Attempting to pull image from camera (${camera.camName}`})
            console.log("Rejected");
        }

        console.log("Going to save file now...");
   //    ... blah blah more code ...
})}

let settledPromises = await Promise.allSettled(ingestPromises)
console.log('All promises settled :>> ', settledPromises);
```

When I run this against an invalid uri, the `retrieveImageFromURI` function throws a timeout error as expected.  This skips the "Record X successful ingestion..." message and jumps to the catch block as expected.  However, then things go unexpectedly.

Output from the above code, when `retrieveImageFromURI` throws an error looks like this:

> ```
> Going to reject
> Rejected
> Going to save file now...
> All promises settled :>>  [ {
>     status: 'rejected',
>     reason: {
>       Task: 'Attempting to pull image from camera (TEST Camera)'
>     }
> }]
> ```

It is my expectation that the reject would stop any further processing within that promise (much like a return would) and I would NOT see 'Rejected' nor 'Going to save file now...' console.logs...

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: A note about using async Promise executor ... don't, just don't i.e. `new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {` if there's something to `await` inside there, there's almost never a reason to construct a new Promise - here's how your code could be written better https://pastebin.com/VRxNYCUr

Comment: Depends what you mean by "to stop running". Do you want to inhibit further iterations of `.map()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about invoking reject. It's just a function. If you want to bail on further processing, your function should `return`.

```js
try {
  imageBuffer = await retrieveImageFromURI(camera.ing_uri)
  console.log(`Record #${i} Successful Ingestion from URI`);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Going to reject");
  reject({ 'Task': `Attempting to pull image from camera (${camera.camName}`})
  console.log("Rejected");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `return` to stop execution, since `reject` is just a function, it can't make the function stop executing.

```js
try {
  // ...
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Going to reject");
  reject({
    'Task': `Attempting to pull image from camera (${camera.camName}`
  });
  console.log("Rejected");
  return;
}
```

If you have a `finally` clause, you will need to add a variable to keep track:

Note: This isn't helpful here, since `finally` is supposed to execute regardless of whether `catch` occurred, but if you have extra checks inside of `catch`, the `return` will go into the `finally` so an extra variable is needed.

```js
let shouldReturn = false;
try {
  // ...
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Going to reject");
  reject({
    'Task': `Attempting to pull image from camera (${camera.camName}`
  });
  console.log("Rejected");
  let shouldReturn = true;
  return;
} finally {
  if (shouldReturn) return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Do I need to return after early resolve/reject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536049/do-i-need-to-return-after-early-resolve-reject) indicates that the first `reject` (or a `resolve`) will define the fullfilled value of a Promise, but they actively do NOT stop execution and a return is needed.