# Why my unit tests are complaining about unhandled promise rejection?

Tags: javascript, exception, promise, es6-promise

I have the below function to print receipts:

```
const generateOnePDF = async (ticket, orderData) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let finalString = '';

    if (!ticket) {
      const err = new Error('missing ticket data');
      reject(err);
    }
    if (!orderData) {
      const err = new Error('missing order data');
      reject(err);
    }

    const { payload, sequence, title } = ticket;

    if (!payload) {
      const err = new Error('missing payload data');
      reject(err);
    }
    if (!sequence) {
      const err = new Error('missing ticket sequence');
      reject(err);
    }
    if (!title) {
      const err = new Error('missing ticket book title');
      reject(err);
    }

    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    PDFDocument.prototype.addSVG = function (svg, x, y, options) {
      return SVGtoPDF(this, svg, x, y, options);
    };

    const stream = doc.pipe(new Base64Encode());

    // logo
    const logo = await fetchImage(
      `${url}/static/media/logo_157.c15ac239.svg`
    );
    doc.addSVG(logo.toString(), 32, 40, {});

    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.text(`Order: O${orderData.orderId}`, { align: 'right' });

    const rectXOffset = 25;
    const rectPosition = 32;
    doc
      .rect(rectXOffset, rectPosition, doc.page.width - rectXOffset * 2, 32)
      .stroke();

    doc.moveDown();
    doc.moveDown();
    doc.moveDown();

    doc.rect(rectXOffset, 80, doc.page.width - rectXOffset * 2, 680).stroke();

    doc.text(orderData.title, { align: 'left' });

    doc.moveDown();

    doc.text(orderData.venue, { align: 'left' });
    doc.text(orderData.address, { align: 'left' });
    doc.text(`${orderData.city}, ${orderData.province} ${orderData.zip}`, {
      align: 'left'
    });

    if (orderData.custom) {
      doc.moveDown();
      doc.text(orderData.customCopy, { align: 'left' });
    }

    doc.moveDown();
    doc.text(`${orderData.date} at ${orderData.show}`, { align: 'left' });

    doc.moveDown();
    const image = await fetchImage(orderData['image']);
    doc.image(image, {
      fit: [100, 100],
      align: 'right',
      valign: 'top'
    });

    doc.moveDown();
    doc.text(
      `Order: O${orderData.orderId}. Placed by ${orderData.firstName} ${orderData.lastName} on ${orderData.created}`
    );


    // right column
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();
    doc.moveUp();

    doc.text(`Ticket: ${sequence} ${title}`, { align: 'right' });

    const qrcode = new QRCode({
      content: payload,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      xmlDeclaration: false,
      join: true
    }).svg();

    const options = { align: 'right' };
    doc.addSVG(qrcode, 400, 150, options);

    // finalize/close the PDF file
    doc.end();

    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      finalString += chunk;
    });

    stream.on('end', () => {
      // the stream is at its end, so push the resulting base64 string to the response
      resolve(finalString);
    });

    stream.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
```

It is not the cleanest piece of code in the world, but it works for me, in the meantime.

I added a simple unit test for this code, below:

```
  it('should throw an error if the ticket or order data are invalid', async () => {
    await expect(generateOnePDF(null, {})).rejects.toThrowError();
    await expect(generateOnePDF({}, null)).rejects.toThrowError();
  });
```

The tests passes, but it writes "garbage" to the console. There are unhandled rejects in the code.

```
(node:53703) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'payload' of '((cov_2gbfm4phuo(...).s[25]++) , ticket)' as it is null.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

is one such error and another is:

```
(node:53703) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'orderId' of null
```

What I don't understand why `if (!ticket) throw()` and `if (!orderData) throw` would not prevent the errors from occurring. Where is the "broken promise?"

I am doing `reject` inside the promise handler function, so where I am not doing it?

Comment: You `reject` and then the function continues execution. Use `return`.

Comment: …or better, simply `throw` your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function still continues executing after `reject` is called, and so errors occur.

Moreover, you should not create a `new Promise` with an `async` callback. That is an anti-pattern. Instead promisify the stream "end" event, and then return that promise.

I would also refrain from defining a function on that `PDFDocument` prototype, and certainly not on *every* call of `generateOnePDF`. You might as well just call that `SVGtoPDF` function directly.

So something like this:

```
const streamPromise = stream =>
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let finalString = '';
        stream.on('data',  chunk => finalString += chunk);
        stream.on('end',   () => resolve(finalString));
        stream.on('error', reject);
    });

const generateOnePDF = async (ticket, orderData) => {
    if (!ticket   ) throw new Error('missing ticket data');
    if (!orderData) throw new Error('missing order data');
    const { payload, sequence, title } = ticket;
    if (!payload  ) throw new Error('missing payload data');
    if (!sequence ) throw new Error('missing ticket sequence');
    if (!title    ) throw new Error('missing ticket book title');
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    const stream = doc.pipe(new Base64Encode());
    // logo
    const logo = await fetchImage(`${url}/static/media/logo_157.c15ac239.svg`);
    SVGtoPDF(doc, logo.toString(), 32, 40, {});
    // ... etc ...
    // ...
    doc.end();
    return streamPromise(stream);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a combination of [using an `async` function for the executor argument to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572) and [not `return`ing early after the `reject()` call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32536049/1048572). Without either of these, you wouldn't both `reject()` the promise and also cause the failure to reject the promise returned by the `async` function. Fixing both, you'd write

```
async function generateOnePDF(ticket, orderData) {
    if (!ticket) throw new Error('missing ticket data');
    if (!orderData) throw new Error('missing order data');
    const { payload, sequence, title } = ticket;
    if (!payload) throw new Error('missing payload data');
    if (!sequence) throw new Error('missing ticket sequence');
    if (!title) throw new Error('missing ticket book title');

    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    const logo = await fetchImage(`${url}/static/media/logo_157.c15ac239.svg`);
    doc.addSVG(logo.toString(), 32, 40, {});

    …

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const stream = doc.pipe(new Base64Encode());

        let finalString = '';
        stream.on('data', chunk => {
          finalString += chunk;
        });
        stream.on('end', () => {
          resolve(finalString);
        });
        stream.on('error', reject);
        doc.end();
    });
});
```